# What's "Ping Site" in CS2 and when should I use it?

Tags: counter-strike-2

I'm new to Counter Strike 2 (on PC) and I can't figure out what's the use of "Ping Site A/B" in the game.

I tried to find articles or helpful videos on YouTube but all I found was "your ping maybe too high or too low due to Internet issues" etc.

They are listed in chat wheels when I press and hold C or V. Selecting them from any of these two menus drops some marker like thing on the ground (as shown in screenshot).

Further, there seems to be other ways to repeat same thing by clicking scroll button on mouse, or merely pressing C or V (without holding).

[image]

[image]

**So I want to understand what is it and when should I use them?**

Comment: Since all of the other items in the wheel menu are, effectively, short messages you can send to your teammates, I would tend to *assume* that "Ping Site A" means something like "Tell my teammates that I think the bomb [is/should be placed] at A."

Answer (score 1):

The wheel of command you access through holding C or V is called the chatwheel, This is used for communication during the game, Pinging a site is used to tell a particular activity, suppose you are at Bombsite B and the Bomb gets planted at A which you know already as you were at B, you can ping B site to let your other teammates know that the Bomb is planted at A by pinging bombsite A.

Pinging can also be used to tell your teammates about the presence of enemies at your sight, let suppose you are again camping at A and you hear footsteps, or the bomb is dropped at A, you can let your teammates know by pinging your site.

there are other roles of pinging a site as well, like if you are a terrorist and you've to plant the bomb, you can let the team know which site you are going by pinging the site.

Hope this helps, Happy Gaming!

Comment: All the other blocks in chatwheel are also other chats with the team like 
"We should save" (to let the team know that you are not willing to buy weapons or buy light weapons to save creds for the next round)
"We should buy" (to let team know you intend to buy weapons, rather than saving)
"follow me" (to request assistance or to guide your mates)
Team chats are important for better coordination between the team and better co-ordination brings in victory.